# Reloaded page to have added content

Tags: javascript, html

On my page I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            if(!window.opener) {
                window.open(window.location.href, '_blank');
            }
        </script>
```

Basically opens 'itself' in a new window, without a constant loop. 
 How can I add 'additional' Javascript content to the new window it opens up, and not the original?

Comment: Are you looking for… `else`?

Comment: The easiest solution here might be to just use a different page in the opened window. Same page, same content (unless you do something interesting with cookies). Different page (can be same base URL with a query string) gets you different content.

Comment: @Zach In this situation, it must be the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.opener) {
        window.open(window.location.href, '_blank');
    } else {
        // ...add additional content here...
    }
</script>
```